# PostgreSQL Error

Tags: postgresql, function

I tried to write function, which would add a new record to the table through input parameters.

Here's code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRec(
    nameuser VARCHAR,
    resultName VARCHAR,
    contents bytea)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
comm VARCHAR;
BEGIN
comm:='INSERT INTO Results_'||nameuser||'(resultName, user, contents) VALUES ('||resultName||', '||nameuser||', '||contents||');';
EXECUTE comm;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

This function call

SELECT addRecDocument ('Fedya', 'Picture", '323423423432')

But i have some error

```
ERROR:  column "picture" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT addRecDocument ('Fedya', Picture, 323423423432)
                                        ^
ERROR: column "picture" does not exist
```

Please, tell me, how fixed this

Comment: `'Picture"` <-- Do you not see that you are mixing single and double quotes?  Actually, I'm surprised you even got this error message.

Comment: Ok, i tryied this SELECT addRecDocument ('Fedya', 'Picture', '323423423432')but the error has remained.

Comment: The function you defined is `addRec`, but you are calling `addRecDocument`.

Comment: Ok, i rename on this SELECT addRec ('Fedya', 'Picture', '323423423432'), but the error has remained. It's strange. He tried find column with this name.

Answer (score 1):

First read about [Quoting Values In Dynamic Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE).

Use `quote_literal` or `quote_nullable`. From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html):

> Return the given string suitably quoted to be used as a string literal
>   in an SQL statement string. Embedded single-quotes and backslashes are
>   properly doubled. Note that quote_literal returns null on null input;
>   if the argument might be null, quote_nullable is often more suitable.

```
comm:='INSERT INTO Results_' || nameuser || '(resultName, user, contents) VALUES (' || quote_literal(resultName) || ', ' || quote_literal(nameuser) || ', ' || quote_literal(contents) || ');';
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you have some time, please, read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)